# Stack Overflow redesign?

Tags: feature-request, design

If there's something that requires no more proof and verification, it is how Jin is incredibly awesome beyond any level of human understanding when it comes to design. So the questions is, can we expect a bit of nice eye candy on SO as well?

Sometimes the rude programmer enjoys a bit of comfort.

Comment: "Jin is incredibly awesome ... when it comes to design" [citation needed]

Comment: How about I just downvote you instead? Ah, whom am I kidding? You're noisy and pointless too.

Comment: [She says she's a webguy.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/users/1685/jin)

Comment: @Stefano, @Jin isn't a she...

Comment: Also I really can't stand Jin's gravatar. What is with all of those lines? They make no sense.

Comment: [ **Some info about Jin, including a photo.** ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/)

Comment: Eye candy? They should convince the Canonical guy to chip in. AskUbuntu makes my mouth water...

Comment: @Toronto Maybe you should read [this](http://www.8164.org/%E2%98%B5%E2%98%B2/)

Comment: @Marco Maybe you should gander at [Toronto's gravatar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/toronto).

Comment: Why is this being closed?  It is a very relevant question.  Now that they have a full-time (presumably) developer, will we see some enhancements to the SO UI?

Comment: I thought it was a female name. I beg pardon, but that's regardless of the point. HIS designs are incredible and I personally think it's time for a redesign of stackoverflow. When I see webapps, or webmasters, and then switch back to SO, I get sad :(

Comment: Redesign it because it's mostly good and has been improving on a regular basis? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Toronto: not from the graphical point of view. I mean, do the comparison. take SO and take webmasters or webapps. They are on totally different levels.

Comment: @Stefano: The differences are superficial.

Comment: @Toronto: they are not superficial. If they were superficial, every promoted area51 site would stay with a stripped to the bone design, and this is not the case. SO is just another area51 site that came out of beta before area51 itself, hence before there was a skilled designer taking care of its appearance.

Comment: @Toronto: of course, if we want to talk about performance/bandwidth, I can understand. SO has an insane traffic when compared to the area51 sites, but some small design improvements won't clog the pipes (I think).

Comment: @Toronto: those lines in his gravatar reminds me of [I Ching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching) trigrams.

Comment: @Grace - haha - I thought Toronto was just a rude son of a gun until I took a gander.

Comment: i don't understand why this is closed either. I've always thought SO was pretty ugly, and seeing how much better the interface can look just reinforces it.

Comment: @Kip : you must understand that some people like to use close as "I don't agree with you".

Comment: @StefanoBorini: Looks like this one should be [status-planned]: my tweet: http://twitter.com/kipthegreat/status/29035776711 jin's reply: http://twitter.com/jzy/status/29086837256

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Jin's comments on Twitter, this one is informally planned (let's give it 6-8 weeks):

[Joel tweeted](http://twitter.com/spolsky/status/29027292863):

> https://photo.stackexchange.com/ has an awesome new design

[I replied](http://twitter.com/kipthegreat/status/29035776711):

> @spolsky i agree! any chance M?S[OFU] will get the @jzy treatment? They're a bit boring... [Stack Overflow redesign?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67513)

[Jin replied](http://twitter.com/jzy/status/29086837256):

> @kipthegreat eventually

Comment: it may be longer than 6-8 weeks, I honestly don't know. Right now I'm focusing on the new SE sites. While I think SOFU could use some form enhancements, function wise it's excellent. This isn't a site that's to win design competitions, and for its purpose, it's quite successful. I think what you and Stefano want is a bit more visual polish, which I do plan to do eventually. But when I do, it won't be a major makeover. I may make incremental tweaks, this way it'd lessen the common anxiety found in most major site's redesigns. Maybe redesign isn't the right word, more like a "re-align."

Comment: @Jin: "6-8 weeks" is a running joke on meta, not to be taken literally, but meaning something more like "sometime in the near or distant future maybe." but thanks for the feedback!  here's a description of the "6-8 weeks" meme: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514

Comment: @Jin : thank you! and a big raspberry to the downvoters :P

Comment: 3 Years later... :P

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, I'd much rather have a functional site than eye candy. Besides, this site is designed better than 99.999% of all the other sites on the World Wide Web, both in function and appearance.

Comment: ok, but if you can have both, why not ?

Comment: You can't have both. Until RockHardAwesome grows up.  Maybe.

Comment: @Hans: what ?...

Comment: So every other SE site is non-functional?