# Stack Overflow UI

Tags: discussion, user-interface, stackexchange-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow redesign?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67513/stack-overflow-redesign)

I know this is of little consequence, but why can't/don't we have a CSS theme or UI that looks better?

It's great already (thanks [@Jin](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1685/jin)) and it doesn't distract you at all, but I still feel that pang of jealousy when I visit sites like [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [English](http://english.stackexchange.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Is the reason that it'll take too much time for such a trivial *(by trivial, I refer to the perceptible gain, NOT the task of creating a new UI)* or non-consequential thing?

Comment: Ouch, somebody just [kicked a designer in the shins](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buHv1EvUHj0). ;)

Comment: I'm so happy this place is free from the freaking visual clutter with which every other new-ish website would seem to strive to substitute its actual content.

Comment: I'm with @GSerg here. Right now a *huge* portion of the screen is given over to actual content, and the rest is given to common tools and useful meta information. This is a *good* thing.

Comment: I'm a fan of Jin's work too, but to be fair, SO and the other original sites were designed before Jin joined the team.

Comment: @PopularDemand Oh... Sorry

Comment: Funny that you're asking for better CSS, yet [keep making posts look worse](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/48568/revisions) by adding these useless `[tag:status-xx]` tags. Please explain why you think that helps?

Comment: @Arjan I said I'm sorry. Please don't stalk me. `[tag:...]` being worse than than text-only `...` is just your opinion.

Comment: True, it's my opinion. But what is the answer to my question?

Comment: @Arjan You mean why I think that help? I don't know. I just like having more semantics added to info. Also, it displays a nice dropdown that gives a brief description of the tag...

Comment: @Arjan ??? _(Wasting chars to bypass minimum char limit)_

Comment: Do you want me to repeat I disagree? (And who needs a description of feature requests or bugs?)

Comment: @Arjan Fine w/e. I'll stop converting everything into custom markup (I don't want a flamewar, please...

Answer (score 15):

> Is the reason that it'll take too much time for such a trivial or non-consequential thing?

Three points:

1. It's not a "trivial or non-consequential thing" to change the design for a site.
2. There's only one full time designer - Jin - working on *the whole network*. Other designers are hired on an "as needed" basis - but only when there's a specific need for external design input.
3. Most people are happy with the design of Stack Overflow. Yes, there are a couple of annoyances, but the site as a whole doesn't *need* a new design so it's a low priority.

Comment: 1) By _'trivial'_, I meant as in the gain from it, NOT the task of creating a better UI

Comment: 2) Oh, so the other sites had hired extra designers or something?

Comment: 3) Yes, I agree. The current one works well and is non-distracting. Just felt a pang of jealousy on visiting the others...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind editing it to reflect my reply to 1)?

Comment: @YatharthROCK - editing it how?

Comment: See my edit (Why does SO impose the 'minimum 15-char comment' thing again?)

Comment: @YatharthROCK So you know that it'll be a non-trival amount of work, for a trivial gain.  How does that support making this change?  Oh, and as ChrisF is saying in his answer, redesiging the UI will have an *enourmous* impact on the end user, whether positive or negative.  It's not likely to be trivial. (or even positive, for that matter; change is bad)

Comment: @Servy Oh well, I guess you're right. I barely notice the UI and that's a good thing...